# Excel keeps freezing on running Macro

Tags: excel, vba

So I am using the following code to make a bunch of decisions based on values in table columns. I have taken each table column containing values that go into making the decision in variant arrays. And then used a combination of for and while loops to assign decisions in the ans() variant array.

The problem is, every time I run the macro my Excel hangs.
I tried the usual method of adding automatic calculations and disabling events and screen updates. But it did not help the matter in any way. I tried simplifying my code as well but this is about as much simplification I can include while still achieving what I would like the code to. Can someone please tell me what else I can do to make this run?

````
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("LOGIC")
Dim t As ListObject
Set t = sh.ListObjects("Table8")
n = t.ListRows.Count

Dim rel() As Variant
rel = t.ListColumns(61).DataBodyRange.Value

Dim dc() As Variant
dc = t.ListColumns(62).DataBodyRange.Value

Dim t_req() As Variant
t_req = t.ListColumns(63).DataBodyRange.Value

Dim sc_req() As Variant
sc_req = t.ListColumns(64).DataBodyRange.Value

Dim x_req() As Variant
x_req = t.ListColumns(65).DataBodyRange.Value

Dim bo() As Variant
bo = t.ListColumns(69).DataBodyRange.Value

Dim ans() As Variant
ans = t.ListColumns(70).DataBodyRange.Value

Dim reqkind() As Variant
reqkind = t.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Value

 For i = 2 To n Step 1
  If rel(i, 1) = 0 Or ans(i, 1) <> 0 Then
   GoTo Nexti
  ElseIf ans(i, 1) = 0 And rel(i, 1) = 1 Then
   While t_req(i, 1) > 0
    For j = i To n - 1
     If dc(i, 1) > 0 Then
      If reqkind(i, 1) = "" Then
       ans(i, 1) = "YES"
       t_req(i, 1) = t_req(i, 1) - 1
       sc_req(i, 1) = sc_req(i, 1) - 1
      ElseIf sc_req(i, 1) <= 0 Then
       ans(i, 1) = "YES"
       t_req(i, 1) = t_req(i, 1) - 1
       x_req(i, 1) = x_req(i, 1) - 1
      Else: GoTo Nextj
      End If
     ElseIf reqkind(i, 1) = "" Then
      If bo(i, 1) > 0 Then
       ans(i, 1) = "YES"
       t_req(i, 1) = t_req(i, 1) - 1
       bo(i, 1) = bo(i, 1) - 1
      Else
       ans(i, 1) = "NO"
       t_req(i, 1) = t_req(i, 1) - 1
      End If
     Else
      ans(i, 1) = "NO"
      t_req(i, 1) = t_req(i, 1) - 1
     End If
Nextj:
    Next j
    Wend
  End If
Nexti:
  Next i```
````

Comment: you while loop keeps testing the same cell and never moves to the next i so once it enters that loop it never leaves.

Comment: Sorry, at what line is that happening could you tell me?

Comment: since this is based on `i`: `While t_req(i, 1) > 0` it will always test the same cell once true.  As it never moves out of that loop to get to the `next i`

Comment: But I update t_req(i,1) inside the conditions that follow. Every time a decision is assigned, it's reduced by one.

Comment: That `While` looks supicious to me, why not just loop `j` and check the `While`'s condition at the appropriate time, then exit the loop if needed. I'm also not fond of the `goto`s. Why not loop normally and use `Exit for` once the exit conditions are met?

Comment: To help with figuring out what's going on, you can put `DoEvents` inside the While loop to enable you to pause the macro. You can also put `Debug.Print` statements to help verify that conditions are being met when expected.

Comment: Side notes: `While...Wend` is deprecated, the [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) is off, the `GoTo`s are suspicious, and maybe consider using more meaningful variable names.

Comment: I tend to agree with others' comments but... You say Excel is "crashing": Please describe that behavior in more detail. Is there an error? Is Excel closing? Or is the macro simply not ending? If the last, then there's an "infinite loop" and the `While` is the most likely culprit. ***Test*** `t_req(i, 1)` either using `Debug.Print` or stepping through the code to check the value or something similar. Since we don't have the workbook and the data, we can't test...

Comment: Thank you everyone. Let me try to change things around and see if it works

Comment: @CindyMeister Excel freezes and says not responding and then I have to go into Task Manager and force close Excel.

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for your help. Managed to restructure the While loop better and the macro runs now.